# Find big o - 3^(n+5)?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, asymptotics, exponential-function

I am unable to find or prove the big O of this expression. Can anyone help me out to prove it?

I tried a lot but didn't find anything to help me solve an expression with polynomial exponent.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The function $n \mapsto 3^{n+5}$ is $O(e^n)$.

Comment: @JivanPal can you please elaborate how?

Comment: Do you seek a proof which appeals to the formal definition of what it means for a function $f$ to be $O(g)$?

Comment: @JivanPal yes I am looking for a proof here.

Comment: Apologies, it is $O(3^n)$. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081673/big-o-notation-of-exponential-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what it needs to be bounded by. Also, the definition of big O vary some, could you write down your definition?

I would assume you want to show that $3^{n+5}=O(3^n)$? If so, simply notice that

$3^{n+5}=3^5 3^n$